# Mystery file on OSX Desktop

Tags: macos, file-management

I have a file that has recently shown up on my desktop, and I'm not sure what it is. I can't delete it, trying gives me the error message

> The item “00000002” can’t be moved to the Trash because it can’t be deleted.

I can't see the file in Terminal.app either. I've attached a screenshot showing it. Any ideas what it is and how I can get rid of it? I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.8

I'm not able to post the screenshot of the problem (not enough rep points yet!), but the file is called 00000002 and it has a PNG icon. I can't see it in Terminal:

```
Als-MacBook-Pro:~ al$ ls -lah ~/Desktop/
total 40
drwx------+  6 al  staff   204B 18 Jul 15:06 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 73 al  staff   2.4K 12 Jul 17:25 ..
drwxrwxrwx@  2 al  staff    68B 28 Oct  2009 .0BF919UDDNUGGF8RBNHSIPCQ
drwxrwxrwx@  2 al  staff    68B 26 Mar  2009 .15YUT6R1TJK0O9
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 al  staff    15K 18 Jul 15:06 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 al  staff     0B 25 Oct  2009 .localized
Als-MacBook-Pro:~ al$
```

Comment: Post a link to the image and someone will edit it into the post.

Comment: Can you do `ls -lAeOR@ ~/Desktop` and update your Question with the output?

Comment: mobiusnz: when you add an inline image, it specifies a URL, with an `!` in front of it. If you don't have enough privileges yet, just remove the `!` from in front to just post a plain link...

Comment: Try typing `ls -leO@ ` (including the space at the end) in Terminal, then drag the file from the Desktop into the terminal window.  What's the file path it pastes in, and what does ls print when you hit return?

Answer (score 1):

00000002 is a "safe save" file from Adobe Fireworks.

Comment: Can you source your statement that that file is indeed created by Adobe Fireworks?

Comment: My source is myself.  I work on a file event monitoring application and Fireworks creates this file as a temporary file before saving to the original.  No idea why they named it that.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an orphan file of sorts, so I'd recommend Disk Utility to scan your drive for any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the tips. I ended up rebooting the computer to install an update, and the file disappeared...

If it shows up again I'll try the `ls -lAeOR@ ~/Desktop` and post the link to the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way - just relaunch Finder from the Force Quit menu (command + option + escape).